# Why does my mod_rewrite .htaccess redirection to another folder get a 404 error?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, directory, add-on

How can I redirect a file to another file in a different folder, which is the physical folder of another add-on domain?

Here's what I have on my server (set by cPanel):

```
  addon_domain_1.com ---> public_html/folder_1
  addon_domain_2.com ---> public_html/folder_2
```

When there's a request for file source.php in addon_domain_1.com, I'd like to redirect it to target.php in folder_2 (not folder_1). So it looks like this:

```
http://www.addon_domain_1.com/blah/source.php ---> folder_2/target.php
```

In my public_html/.htaccess file, I have the following:

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks All -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon_domain_1\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule /source\.php$ folder_2/target\.php [L]
```

But this produces a 404 error:

```
  Not Found
  The requested URL /home/username/public_html/folder_2/target.php was not found on this server.
```

In reality, the file target.php does exist in folder_2 and is accessible through the browser.

The strange thing is that when I copy target.php to folder_1, and change my rule to point to it, it works fine!

```
  RewriteRule /source\.php$ folder_1/target\.php [L]
```

So, it seems the error occurs only if I redirect it to a file in a folder that is the source of a different add-on domain.

How can I get around this??

Please note that I cannot use the external redirection  because it would lose the original environment variables such as REQUEST_URI and REMOTE_ADDR that my script needs.

In other words, the following rule would not work for me:

```
  RewriteRule /source\.php$ http://www\.addon_domain_2.com/target\.php [P,L]
```

I know you can also "attach" the environment variables in the query string, but I'd rather not use this method, and let my PHP script handles it.

Thank you.